# Java library to compare shapefiles

Tags: java, geotools

I have county shapefile and school district shapefile.

Once each school district file is overlay on county shapefile I would like to know how much percentage of area of school district file covered by each county shapefile.

Any idea how I can use GeoTools Java library or any other Java library to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic algorithm for this is:

- read in districts
- read in counties
- foreach district in districts

  - split district by counties
  - calculate area as % of original

GeoTools (and JTS) are able to take care of all of these steps for you, the [quickstart tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/index.html) will have shown you how to read in your shapefiles. The [query tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/filter/query.html) will get you up to speed on FeatureCollections and filters.

To split a feature's geometry you will need to use [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/) which GeoTools wraps for you as [Geometry Operations](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jts/operation.html).

Your inner loop will look something like (untested code):

```
Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("INTERSECTS(the_geom,"+district.toWKT()+")");
SimpleFeatureCollection features = counties.getFeatures(filter);
SimpleFeatureIterator it = features.features();
while(it.hasNext()){
  SimpleFeature next = (SimpleFeature)it.next();
  Geometry overlap =  district.intersection(next.getDefaultGeometry());
  double area = overlap.getArea();
}
```

I've knocked up a [full example](https://gitlab.com/snippets/7461) too.

Comment: Thanks. I am using latest version of GEO Tools Which is 13.1.I m getting error Error while parsing JAI registry file "file:geotools-13.2/imageio-ext-imagereadmt-1.1.11.jar!/META-INF/registryFile.jai" :
Error in registry file at line number #29.   A descriptor is already registered against the name "ImageReadMT" under registry mode "rendered"
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sg.gis.schooldistict.features.Overlaps.overlap(Overlaps.java:67)
at sg.gis.schooldistict.features.Overlaps.main(Overlaps.java:34). Should i be using another version of GEO Tools?

Comment: I don't think the first issue is related to the second one. See what line 67 is using

Comment: I used the exact same code u provided which is very cool. Error i see it is        System.out.println("100.00% of "+feature.getAttribute("NAME")+" is in "+ f2.getAttribute("NAME"));
One thing is this is my first GIS related program so may be i m giving wrong input. I am using tl_2010_01_tract10/tl_2010_01_tract10.shp from census website. It has few other files like dbf,prj etc. Should i be using ".shp" file as input?

Comment: Do you have an attribute called NAME?  You will need to modify the attribute names to match your data or delete those lines